# buy a kitchen? How could this be possible?

Tags: vocabulary

My Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary has the following example sentence:

> You can buy the kitchen as a flat-pack for self-assembly.

How could one buy a kitchen? It doesn't make much sense to me. The kitchen is a cooking place and is supposed to be part of a house, apartment, etc. and not sold separately.

Comment: Looking at the title, I really thought this was going to be a spam post.

Comment: Is there really any country on this planet where you really _can’t_ buy a kitchen? I find that very hard to believe. This is not about the English language, it's about living under a rock… on Mars!

Comment: I come from a culture where kitchens, houses, etc. are more likely to be made of concrete, not wood.

Comment: I must echo Janus Bahs Jacquet's observation, even if the OP is used to kitchens being made of [concrete](http://machamalaria.net/sep06pics.html) I find it difficult to believe that he has never seen a typical Canadian, American, European, Asian or Australian kitchen in films, on TV, in magazines, or on the Internet. Never visited a furniture store that also sold kitchen units?

Comment: What do you mean by 'kitchen units'? Stuff like cupboards and cabinets? OF course I have seen them, but I didn't know they can be called 'kitchen' for short. For me, 'kitchen' is basically a cooking place. How could one buy a place to the exclusion of the other parts of a house, apartment, etc.?

Comment: Like any room of a house, people buy furniture for that particular space. Perhaps it is unusual to say "I want to buy a bathroom" when visiting a furniture shop, but you can definitely say: "I need to change my bathroom." Meaning you want to change the fixtures or the furniture in that room. For example, the bathtub, the wash basin, the toilet etc. When buying a kitchen, one is buying the electrical appliances, the cabinets, the shelves etc. that go *in* a kitchen room.

Comment: @Apollyon, you can think of ‘kitchen’ here as meaning not so much 一间厨房, but more 一套厨房（设备）. For example, on IKEA Taiwan’s web site, they say you can _立刻看看我們的空間搭配，找到專屬你家風格廚房_, using the term in the same manner. If you can 找到专属你家风格的厨房 at IKEA, it stands to reason that you can also 买到专属你家风格的厨房 there.

Comment: I know 'kitchen' in English can refer to fixtures, equipment, in a kitchen now. My comments here are responses to Janus Bahs Jacquet's surprised reaction at my question, which is essentially a matter of the difference between English and Chinese. 廚房 always refers to the cooking place in Chinese, unlike "kitchen" in English. (P.S. I find your Chinese examples unnatural. 找到专属你家风格的厨房 may be interpreted  to mean to find a kitchen style that suits your house. But 买到专属你家风格的厨房 makes no sense.一套厨房设备 sounds fine, but 設備 isn't optional here.)

Comment: This is a reasonable -cultural- question. Why would anyone -ever- imagine that you buy a room? You buy the house or you build an additional room to a house, then _furnish_ one of those rooms to have a particular function. But to buy the functional unit itself seems bizarre. You buy a bed or a bedroom set, but not the bedroom as a whole unit. Of course, I _have_ been to Ikea where you do indeed buy a kitchen. But this is really not about English.

Comment: In view of the fact that both Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary and Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English do not record the fixture sense of 'kitchen' and that 'kitchen' does not find its exact counterpart in Chinese, this is a question of the English language.

Comment: Of course Chinese speakers wouldn't believe one could buy a room. So as soon as I saw the example sentence, not knowing the fixture sense of 'kitchen', I looked up its entry, only to find its cooking-place sense.

Answer (score 5):

Here, *kitchen* is referring to the shelves, etc., that would normally go in the room we call a "kitchen." In the US, this is often would include the stove/oven combination, but it can also refer to shelving specific to kitchens.

Note the following definition from google supplied at the top of the search results:

> a room or area where food is prepared and cooked.
>
> a set of fixtures, cabinets, and appliances that are sold together and installed in a room  where food is prepared.
>
> "a complete kitchen at a bargain price"

Thus, here they mean the kit that composes what you need to turn a space into a kitchen room.

Comment: @Susan, Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[Camp Kitchen](http://www.desirethis.com/558/gander-mountain-deluxe-camp-kitchen)

[image]

[More images at this link.](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=camper%20kitchen&FORM=HDRSC2)

Also, if you are familiar with the home furnishing store IKEA, you  know their products are sold in flat-packs for self-assembly. See [this article](http://www.thekitchn.com/faiths-kitchen-renovation-the-trials-and-joys-of-buying-an-ikea-kitchen-renovation-diary-faiths-budg-184072), "Faith's Kitchen Renovation: 5 Things We Learned While Buying an IKEA Kitchen" and the [follow-on article](http://www.thekitchn.com/faiths-kitchen-renovation-how-we-assembled-and-installed-our-custom-ikea-kitchen-renovation-diary-fa-185658) "How We Assembled and Installed Our IKEA Kitchen".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that ovens are flat packed. In the quote the kitchen is much more likely to be the *room* itself, presumably with a countertop, cabinets and maybe a pantry. Think of a kit from Ikea. Outside the U.S. many people create everything from the floor up, including the floor, from flat-packed kits and take it all with them when they move.

Comment: How could one buy a room, e.g. a kitchen, to the exclusion of other parts of an apartment? How could a room be sold in a 'flat-pack'? Obviously, 'kitchen' in this context refers to equipment necessary to convert a place into a kitchen, not a kitchen itself.

Comment: @Apollyon a kitchen without appliances, fixtures, cupboards etc. is just a room like any other. When newlyweds buy a home, usually the rooms are unfurnished and they will set out "to buy": a kitchen, a bedroom, a bathroom and so on, they are not buying the rooms of a house. It's just quicker to say that than to say; kitchen appliances, a sink, a kitchen island, counters, chairs and a table. What do people in Taiwan say instead?

Comment: We say the equivalent of kitchen, bathroom, etc. equipment in Chinese

Answer (score 0):

At one time, you could buy a flat-pack [house](http://myflatpackhome.com/ketc-living-st-louis-sears-homes/) from Sears; and you can can still [buy](http://www.flatpakhouse.com/) a flat pack house (but I don't think my local Sears keeps them in stock).